Firebase security rule for users to access other users data
I want my users in my flutter app to be able to access other users recipes if the other user allowed them. I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore as the DB. So if the current user is part of the requested users usersAllowedToRead collection then they can also access the other users recipes.
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   
    match /users/{userId} {
      // Allow the user to read and write their own document
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /recipes/{recipeId} {
        // Allow read access if the user is authenticated and either is the user document owner
        // or is listed in the 'usersAllowedToRead' subcollection of the user document
        allow read: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == userId || exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/usersAllowedToRead/$(request.auth.uid)));
        // Allow write access only if the user is authenticated and is the user document owner
        allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }  
  }

But I always get an error stating that access is denied. When I tested it in the firebase rule playground then the exists evaluates to false even when the current user is present in the other user's usersAllowedToRead collection.
This path exists in my db: /users/VJ1DcW.../usersAllowedToRead/MmrFH... but when I execute a get call then the exists method evaluates to false and I can't figure out why.

There's not enough information here to know what's wrong.  Please edit the question to show the query you're making, as well as the contents of all relevant documents.  You should also ensure that your code proves that the user is signed in by printing their UID.  Without all these facts, we really don't know what these rules are actually going to do.  There needs to be enough information to reproduce the unexpected behavior.

My guess is that your query (which you didn't include in the question) is trying to read the entire recipes subcollection of the user, which won't work since Firebase security rules don't filter the data. Rather the rules engine just ensures that any data access from a client-side SDK matches the rules that you've set for that data.
Your current code will work when you request a single document, but not for list style queries as Firestore cannot actually inspect the data for all potential documents in a scalable way. For list-style calls you'll use a query and you have to make sure that your query meets the conditions of your rules, something which isn't possible with the current rules you have - as there's no way to write a query that checks the same thing as the exists call in your rule does.
So you'll need to change the data structure to ensure that all data that is needed for the query is inside of the documents that the query actually returns. Once you do that, your rules can also filter on that data - and once the rules and query match up, the code will work.
